# Cannot remove directories Ubuntu Server

Tags: 14.04, command-line

I recently was moving directories around on my server and something happened. It was a few weeks ago, so I do not remember exactly what happened. These directories are now unusable and unreadable. I cannot enter them and my programs cannot read them. Since they are taking up a large amount of disk space, I have tried to delete them. I used the command

```
sudo rm nameOfFolder -R
```

But it says that there is no such file or directory. However, if I do the command "ls" the directories show up fine. I did some googling, and tried another command,

```
rm -rf nameOfFolder
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Type the 1st letter(s) of the directory and then press TAB until it completes the directory name. There might be some unprintable character in it.

Answer (score 0):

Arguments such as `-R` almost always precede the target of the command. Your first command had the argument after the target and since there was no `nameOfFolder -R` you will get `no such file or directory`. Suggest that you read `man rm` and `man rmdir` for details of syntax and available arguments.

If the folders are showing up in Nautilus, you can always drag them to the Terminal window after entering the command and arguments and the path to the target will be entered automatically.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Sorry, that was actually an error in me writing up the question. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: You can put -R at the end if you want ... `mkdir test` following with  `rm test -rf` works.